# how to disable motion of ViewPager when touching specific view in this ViewPager Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a ViewPager. In each pager, it display a listview. Each row in the Listview contains a HorizontalScrollView element. Here is the code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/survey_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/store_name"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_store_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>           

    </LinearLayout>

    <HorizontalScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/survey_header"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <TableLayout 
            android:id="@+id/survey_table"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TableRow 
                android:id="@+id/survey_table_row"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/txt_status"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/red_text"/>
                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/txt_product"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/red_text"/>
                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/txt_stock"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/red_text"/>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow 
                android:id="@+id/menu_table_row"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/red_text"
                    android:text="@string/survey_status"/>
                <TextView 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/red_text"
                    android:text="@string/product_info"/>
                <TextView 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/red_text"
                    android:text="@string/stock_count"/>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Everytime I try to scroll the horizontal Scroll View, the ViewPager receives touch event first and change the page.

How can I disable the changing page of ViewPager when I touch Horizontal Scorll View.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
HorizontalScrollView scrollView=(HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView); 


scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            float rawX;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        scrollView.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                        rawX = event.getRawX();
                        return false;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        scrollView.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                        rawX = 0f;
                        return false;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        if (Math.abs(rawX - event.getRawX()) > ViewConfiguration.get(getActivity()).getScaledTouchSlop())
                            scrollView.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

                        break;
                }


                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: I try your solution, but it doesn't work. The ViewPager still swipe when I scroll the ScrollView inside it.

Comment: try to move scrollView.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false); method to  case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

Comment: I try if                       scrollView.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true); in case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, now It goes well. Thanks a lot